# Using a dataframe name from the dataframes list in the axis name in a ggplot plot

Tags: r, dataframe, list, ggplot2

I have a list of data frames

[image]

Based on this, I prepare `ggplot` charts

```
co_gpl <- lapply(co_lst, function(x) {
  ggplot(x) + 
    geom_line (aes (x = `Czas`, y = get(names(x[grep("Temp. zasilania", colnames (x))])) ), color = "red3", size = 0.3) +
    geom_line (aes (x = `Czas`, y = get(names(x[grep("Temp. powrotu", colnames (x))]))), color = "blue3", size = 0.3) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min.T.pow, max.T.zas))  +
    scale_x_datetime(date_labels = format ("%H:%M"),
                     minor_breaks = "1 hour") +
    labs (y = paste0("", "/Temperatura [°C]")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
          legend.position = "top",
          legend.justification = "center") 
})

ggp <- wrap_plots (co_gpl, nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
```

I would like the name dataframe to appear in the x-axis title (A5, B5, K1 respectively). An Alternative option is to have each chart have a subtitle that contains the name of its data frame.

Adding `names(x)` does not do what is needed

```
co_gpl <- lapply(co_lst, function(x) {
  ggplot(x) + 
    geom_line (aes (x = `Czas`, y = get(names(x[grep("Temp. zasilania", colnames (x))])) ), color = "red3", size = 0.3) +
    geom_line (aes (x = `Czas`, y = get(names(x[grep("Temp. powrotu", colnames (x))]))), color = "blue3", size = 0.3) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min.T.pow, max.T.zas))  +
    scale_x_datetime(date_labels = format ("%H:%M"),
                     minor_breaks = "1 hour") +
    labs (y = paste0(names(x), "/Temperatura [°C]")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
          legend.position = "top",
          legend.justification = "center") 
})
```

**EDIT**

```
A5 <- data.frame( Time = c(as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 14:30:01'), as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 15:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 15:30:00'), as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 16:00:00'),as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 16:30:00')),
                 `[A5] zuzycie` = rnorm(5, 1, 1),
                 `[A5] temp` = rnorm(5, 10, 1),
                 `[A5] level` = rnorm(5, 20, 10)
                 )

B5 <- data.frame( Time = c(as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 14:30:01'), as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 15:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 15:30:00'), as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 16:00:00'),as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 16:30:00')),
                  `[B5] zuzycie` = rnorm(5, 1, 1),
                  `[B5] temp` = rnorm(5, 10, 1),
                  `[B5] level` = rnorm(5, 20, 10)
)

K1 <- data.frame( Time = c(as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 14:30:01'), as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 15:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 15:30:00'), as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 16:00:00'),as.POSIXct('2023-07-26 16:30:00')),
                  `[K1] zuzycie` = rnorm(5, 1, 1),
                  `[K1] temp` = rnorm(5, 10, 1),
                  `[K1] level` = rnorm(5, 20, 10)
)

co_lst2 <- list (A5=A5, B5=B5, K1=K1)

co_gpl <- lapply(co_lst2, function(x) {
  ggplot(x) + 
    geom_line (aes (x = `Time`, y = get(names(x[grep("temp", colnames (x))])) ), color = "red3", size = 0.3) +
    labs (y = paste0("", "/Temperatura [°C]")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
          legend.position = "top",
          legend.justification = "center") 
})

ggp <- wrap_plots (co_gpl, nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
ggp
```

Comment: As `co_lst` is a named list you could e.g. use `purrr::imap` or `mapply` to pass the name as a second argument to your function. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snippet like `get(names(x[grep("Temp. zasilania", colnames (x))]))` seems like extremely bad style.

But to answer the question: If you need access to the list names, you can use

```
lapply(names(co_lst), function(nm) {
    ggplot(co_lst[[nm]], ...) +
      ggtitle(nm)
  }
)
```

### Edit: Getting rid of `get()` -> `.data[[]]`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

A5 <- data.frame( 
  Time = as.POSIXct(
    c('2023-07-26 14:30:01', 
      '2023-07-26 15:00:00', 
      '2023-07-26 15:30:00', 
      '2023-07-26 16:00:00', 
      '2023-07-26 16:30:00')
  ),
  "[A5] zuzycie" = rnorm(5, 1, 1),
  "[A5] temp" = rnorm(5, 10, 1),
  "[A5] level" = rnorm(5, 20, 10),
  check.names = FALSE
)

B5 <- data.frame( 
  Time = as.POSIXct(
    c('2023-07-26 14:30:01', 
      '2023-07-26 15:00:00',
      '2023-07-26 15:30:00',
      '2023-07-26 16:00:00',
      '2023-07-26 16:30:00')
  ),
  "[B5] zuzycie" = rnorm(5, 1, 1),
  "[B5] temp" = rnorm(5, 10, 1),
  "[B5] level" = rnorm(5, 20, 10),
  check.names = FALSE
)

K1 <- data.frame( 
  Time = as.POSIXct(
    c('2023-07-26 14:30:01', 
      '2023-07-26 15:00:00', 
      '2023-07-26 15:30:00', 
      '2023-07-26 16:00:00', 
      '2023-07-26 16:30:00')
  ),
  "[K1] zuzycie" = rnorm(5, 1, 1),
  "[K1] temp" = rnorm(5, 10, 1),
  "[K1] level" = rnorm(5, 20, 10),
  check.names = FALSE
)

co_lst2 <- list(A5 = A5, B5 = B5, K1 = K1)

co_gpl <- lapply(co_lst2, function(x) {
  ggplot(x) + 
    geom_line(
      aes(x = `Time`, y = .data[[grep("temp", colnames(x), value = TRUE)]]), 
      color = "red3", 
      size = 0.3
    ) +
    labs(y = "/Temperatura [°C]") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
          legend.position = "top",
          legend.justification = "center") 
})

ggp <- wrap_plots (co_gpl, nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
ggp
```

### Edit 2: More ggplot-like

```
X <- list(A5 = A5, B5 = B5, K1 = K1) |> 
  lapply(pivot_longer, -Time) |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "source") |> 
  mutate(name = factor(substring(name, 6)))

ggplot(X, aes(x = Time, y = value, group = name, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap("source") +
  labs(color = "Variable")

# Or even
ggplot(X, aes(x = Time, y = value)) +
  geom_line(color = "red") +
  facet_grid(name ~ source)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your time. I also appreciate your comment about bad style. Can you indicate how this should be done?

Comment: If you give me a small example, I can try. Maybe you can directly use y = `Temp. zasilania` (with backquotes)?

Comment: Great help. Thank you very much. Can the y-axis title be supplemented with a dataframe name in the first version?

Comment: I think you would need to switch to the `lapply(names())` logic, or replace the `lapply()` by a `mapply()` and also pass the names. But that is harder to read.